# 'permission denied' .load'ing the current page on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, same-origin-policy

Say I'm testing a site on the sub-folder of a server, e.g. `http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/`. When I'm on the root page, I can happily do a

```
$('#dummy').load('http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/page.html')
```

(A callback function alerting a success message would fire.) However, if I try

```
$('#dummy').load('http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/folder/page.html')
```

I get the 'permission denied' error only in IE (same origin policy error).

I get the same success/failure if I omit the IP address, i.e. `$('#dummy').load('/domain.tld/...')`. I have no idea why IE would behave like this; it's just a subfolder. (In fact, it's Wordpress with a `.html` extension plugin, but I can't see that being the issue.)

**edit:** It turns out I get the permission denied only when loading the page that I'm currently browsing. For instance, assume my browser is pointed at `http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/folder/page.html`, if I then try

```
$('#dummy').load('http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/folder/page.html')
```

then the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as described, the precise problem is that IE didn't like loading a URL if it was already on it. If the browser is at `http://123.12.12.12/domain.tld/page.html` for *any* `page.html` in *any* sub-directory structure, the following jQuery would fail:

```
$('#container').load('http://123.12.12.12/domain.tld/page.html');
```

The failure is characterised by a 'Permission denied' error, commonly associated with the same origin policy.

To fix the problem, append a dummy object to the request, which forces jQuery to send it as a POST request (rather than the default GET), e.g.:

```
$('#container').load('http://123.12.12.12/domain.tld/page.html', {one : 1});
```

and the load now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied is from the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Accessing data from a folder is not going to be the issue. I am guessing that what is in the address for your browser is not `http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld`.

Comment: `$('#dummy').load('http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/page.html')` and `$('#dummy').load('http://12.123.12.12/domain.tld/folder/page.html')
` should have no problems when accessed from `http://12.123.12.12` or any of the folders in the directory.

Comment: Is page.html a full document or just a fragment. If it is a full document, you will have two headers, bodies, etc. Bad design.